# PreferenceFragment has holo design in Android 6.0

Tags: android, preferencefragment

My phone is Android 6.0 but preferencefragment has mixed design with holo and material design.
I want to change its design to perfect material design.
But i can't change it.

My PreferenceFragment java code.
I used android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

```
public class AboutFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_about_general);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add this lib in your build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.2.1'
```

EDIT:

Add this in your style.xml file :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        //below your own item            
        ...
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>

</style>
```

And define your PreferenceTheme :

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorid</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorid</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorid</item>
    </style>
```

But in your code you use the v7 version, the v14 is just for material design support.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i use it and edit java code to 'import android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment;', i can see this error.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference